# How I can receive FCM notification only when app is terminated and doesn't receive it if app is working in background

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm handling FCM in my flutter app and i want only to receive one scheduled notification if my app is terminated and i don't want to receive it if app is working in the background now.

This is my code and when i'm testing i'm receiving this notification if my app is in background or is terminated.

```
Future<void> background_handler(RemoteMessage message) async {
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
}
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: FirebaseOptions(apiKey: 
    "apikey", appId: "appid", messagingSenderId: "senderid", projectId: "projid"));


    //handle msg in terminate case
    RemoteMessage? message = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if(message != null){

     PushNotification notification = new PushNotification(title: 
       message.notification?.title?? "Title",
       body: message.notification?.body?? "Body", dataTitle: message.data["title"], 
       dataBody: message.data["body"] );

     }

     FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(background_handler);
     runApp(const MyApp());
 }
```

How I can change this code to make app only receive this notification if it's terminated, or it's not possible to separate the background and terminated cases?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible since [`onBackgroundMessage`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#message-types) handles messages when the app is in both background and terminated state. Also, Flutter can only detect if the app is in background but [not when it's terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060166/20447561).